# How to set Gmail as default mailer in OS X?

Tags: email, google-chrome, macos

I want to open Gmail when I click a `mailto` link in Chrome in OS X.

Some web pages claim that I can set as default Email client in Chrome by `chrome://settings/handlers`. But in my environment, it shows nothing.

How can I open `mailto` link in Chrome in OS X?

Comment: See also: [How can I use Gmail as the default mail client app in Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3029)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search shows you will need to download an application called "Google Notifier".

Full instructions can be found at [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10966).

One quick note: Would you not consider using your Gmail account in the Apple Mail client? Might be easier.

Comment: Google notified is no longer supported - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10960?rd=1